# display a date in particular format from month array in php

Tags: php, arrays, date, french

I have a php code as shown below in which there is an array of french months.

```
<?php
$months = array(
    1 => "janvier",
    2 => "février",
    3 => "mars",
    4 => "avril",
    5 => "mai",
    6 => "juin",
    7 => "juillet",
    8 => "août",
    9 => "septembre",
    10 => "octobre",
    11 => "novembre",
    12 => "décembre",
);
?>
```

**Problem Statement:**

What I want to achieve is I want to display a date in the following format:

```
08 août 2020
```

For the first day of the month, append er to the number:

```
e.g. 1er août 2020
```

**This is what I have tried**. Although it's working as `Line A prints 08 août 2020` but I am wondering if its gonna work in all cases. All cases here means for all days of the month.

I have hardcoded the value at Line Z but it will change.

```
<?php
$months = array(
    1 => "janvier",
    2 => "février",
    3 => "mars",
    4 => "avril",
    5 => "mai",
    6 => "juin",
    7 => "juillet",
    8 => "août",
    9 => "septembre",
    10 => "octobre",
    11 => "novembre",
    12 => "décembre",
);
$this_date="2020-08-08";   // Line Z 
$this_time = strtotime($this_date);
$day = date('d', $this_time);
$month = date('n', $this_time);
$month_fr = $months[$month];
$suffix = $day == 1 ? 'er' : '';
$formatted_new_fr = strftime("%d$suffix " . $month_fr . " %Y", $this_time);
echo $formatted_new_fr;  // Line A
?>
```

Comment: I was about to post some tips, but they're more code review than anything else. I think this question doesn't fit this site as it doesn't actually specify a problem (your code works, as far as you know); maybe it could be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead? (Be sure to read their help pages first.)

Comment: @xNoJustice What does timezone have to do with month names? Are you confusing it with "locale"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP got you covered :)

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');

$dateString = '2020-08-08';
$timestamp = strtotime($dateString);
$formattedDate = strftime('%d %B %Y', $timestamp);
//setlocale(LC_ALL, Locale::getDefault()); // restore (if neccessary)

echo utf8_encode($formattedDate);
```

### output

```
08 août 2020
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/F62Sj).

To get the `1er` day you can do what you already did. Just split up the strftime(or its result).

### references

- [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)
- [setlocale](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale)

---

### another solution (will display all days ordinally though)

```
$locale = 'fr_FR';
$dateString = '2020-08-01';
$date = new DateTimeImmutable($dateString);
$dateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    $locale,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    NULL
);

$numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
$ordinalDay = $numberFormatter->format($date->format('d'));
$dateFormatter->setPattern('LLLL Y');

echo $ordinalDay . ' ' . $dateFormatter->format($date->getTimestamp());
```

### output

```
1er août 2020
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/P55so).

### references

- [Pattern for DateFormatter](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)
- [NumberFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)